# Pyspark: Check if Array Type Column Contains a Value From a List

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Is there a way to check if an `ArrayType` column contains a value from a list? It doesn't have to be an actual python list, just something spark can understand. I'd like to do with without using a `udf` since they are best avoided.

For example, I have the data:

```
+-------------+
|category_code|
+-------------+
|         [88]|
|     [20, 50]|
+-------------+
```

I want to check if one of `[43, 44, 50]` are in each row, so the output would be:

```
+-------------+-----+
|category_code| test|
+-------------+-----+
|         [88]|false|
|     [20, 50]| true|
+-------------+-----+
```

I'm aware of the function `pyspark.sql.functions.array_contains()` but this only allows to check for one value rather than a list of values.

Edit: This is for Spark 2.4

Comment: Preferably spark 2.4 but if spark 3.0 has a solution I'd happily hear that.

Comment: @mazaneicha I don't think this is a duplicate since Spark SQL and pyspark are different API's

Comment: @fungie127 See the last answer in referenced post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [arrays_overlap](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#arrays_overlap) function & It is available from `Spark 2.4.0`.

Check below code.

```
>>> df.show()
+-------------+
|category_code|
+-------------+
|     [20, 50]|
|         [88]|
+-------------+
```

```
df.withColumn("list",F.array([F.lit(i) for i in [40,44,50]])) \
.withColumn("test",F.arrays_overlap(F.col("category_code"),F.col("list"))) \
.drop("list") \
.show()
+-------------+-----+
|category_code| test|
+-------------+-----+
|     [20, 50]| true|
|         [88]|false|
+-------------+-----+
```